# Winforms Trouble passing value between forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am having trouble passing data from one form to another.  I have looked at several examples and tried them, but nothing is working.

In "Estimate" Form this is what opens the "EstimateTakeoffItemAdd" Form...

```
    private void TakeoffGridAdd(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(AutoID.ToString());

        int index = 0;

        if (AutoID > 0)
        {
        }
     }

    private void addDialog()
    {
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.ToString() != "c")
        {
            using (var et = new EstimateTakeoffItemAdd(estID, Convert.ToInt32(treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(SheetSelector.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(BidItemSelector.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(SortCodeSelector.SelectedValue)))
            {
                et.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(TakeoffGridAdd);
                et.ShowDialog();
                AutoID = et.AddedID;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the "EstimateTakeoffItemAdd" Form this is the function that saves/closes the form...

```
    public int AddedID { get; set; }
    public bool ItemAdded { get; set; }

    private void radButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pricemod = (Convert.ToDecimal(LaborText.Text) == dbLabor) ? 0 : 1;
        pricemod = (Convert.ToDecimal(MaterialText.Text) == dbPrice) ? 0 : 1;

        try
        {
            DBConnector db = new DBConnector();
            db.query = "SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='tb_estimate_takeoff'";                
            this.AddedID = Convert.ToInt32(db.executeScalar());
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                DBConnector db = new DBConnector();
                db.query = "INSERT INTO tb_estimate_takeoff (item, estimate, sheet, qty, hrs, mat, biditem, phase, matunit_mod, labunit_mod, guid) VALUES (" +
                           "'" + DescriptionText.Text + "', " +
                           estID + ", " +
                           sheet + ", " +
                           QtyText.Value + ", " +
                           LaborText.Text + ", " +
                           MaterialText.Text + ", " +
                           biditem + ", " +
                           phase + ", " +
                           pricemod + ", " +
                           labormod + ", " +
                           "'" + guid + "'" +
                          ")";
                db.executeNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                ItemAdded = true;
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

What I need is to get the AddedID back to the main "Estimate" form.  Using a MessageBox before closing "EstimateTakeoffItemAdd" I can see that AddedID is working on that form, however it shows a 0 on the "Estimate" form.

After opening the dialog and closing for the second time, the first AddedID is then available to the "Estimate" form.

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks fine. `however it shows a 0 on the "Estimate" form.` <-- Can you show us where you do this?.  Also, when you step through your code in the debugger, and you look at the value of `et.AddedID` on the line `AutoID = et.AddedID;`, what do you see?

Comment: By using the Message box in the FormClosing function...Edited above.

Comment: Can you edit your post instead of putting it in the comment?  That way, it will have proper formatting, and everyone else will see it as well. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about this: `SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table...`? I can't see any `Auto_Increment` column in `information_schema.Tables` and this leads to unexpected behavior in the following code. What database are you using?

Comment: @Steve When I place a MessageBox before the Close statement on this form it displays the proper value.

Comment: The TakeoffGridAdd() method is buggy, it uses the AutoId variable before it is assigned.   You shot your leg off by not using the dialog properly, get rid of the FormClosing event handler.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the value is getting passed just fine.  You are simply testing the value at the wrong time from the wrong place.

It would appear that you have registered the `TakeoffGridAdd` event handler to execute when the `EstimateTakeoffItemAdd` form is closing.

If this is true, then the line:

```
et.ShowDialog();
```

... hasn't returned yet, because the form is not closed yet.  That means that the assignment `AutoID = et.AddedID;` also hasn't executed yet.

Because your method `EstimateTakeoffItemAdd` is running ***before*** the assignment is made, you always appear to be reading an old value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Hans Passant and @sstan.  Getting rid of the FormClosing event handler solved my problem.

```
    private void addDialog()
    {
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.ToString() != "c")
        {
            using (var et = new EstimateTakeoffItemAdd(estID, Convert.ToInt32(treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(SheetSelector.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(BidItemSelector.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(SortCodeSelector.SelectedValue)))
            {
                if (et.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    AutoID = et.AddedID;
                    TakeoffGridAdd();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```